# Puppet: conditional restart of service

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to conditionally skip refresh events on a `service` resource? Or alternatively: Is it possible to prevent a `service` resource inside a class to be refreshed when the class is notified?

---

Context: I have a Puppet module containing the following manifest (simplified):

```puppet
class foo(
  Boolean pre_process_service  = true,
  Boolean auto_restart_service = true
) {
  if $pre_process_service {
    exec { 'process config':
      ... # details including a pretty complex command - should be hidden in my module
      notify => Service['foo'],
    }
  }

  service { 'foo':
    ensure => 'running',
    enable => true,
  }
}
```

which might be used like so:

```puppet
file { 'config':
  ... # copies config from somewhere
}

class { 'foo':
  auto_restart_service => false,
  subscribe            => File['config'],
}
```

How can I avoid restarting the service when the user specifies `auto_restart_service => false`?

Note that the user of the module decides how to provide the configuration (copying files, checking out a Git repository,...) so I can't do that inside my module. Instead the class subscribes to the resource providing the configuration. As long as the user goes with the default of `auto_restart_service = true` everything works fine and even disabling the preprocessing of the configuration works correctly. However, when the user specifies `auto_restart_service = false` the service will still restart since the `service` resource is refreshed when the class is notified. Wrapping the service resource into an `if` block like I did with the `exec` resource doesn't work either since the `service` resource does multiple things:

1. It starts the service if it isn't running
2. It enables the service if it isn't enabled
3. It restarts the service if notified

I only want to conditionally prevent (3) from happening while always doing (1) and (2). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to not refresh the service when you notify the class. However, you can try to conditionally override how Puppet should restart the service with the `restart` attribute of the `service` resource.

Something like this:

```
if $auto_restart_service {

  # Let the provider handle the restart
  $_attr = {}

} else {

  # Let Puppet execute `true` instead of actually restarting the service
  $_attr = { 'restart' => '/usr/bin/true' }

}

service { 'foo':
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => true,
  *      => $_attr,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea from **tectux** is really nice. I've enhanced the if conditions. I have decided to use script for custom fact.

modules/autofs/facts.d/autofs.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
DECISION=`test -f /usr/bin/docker && /usr/bin/docker ps -q |grep -q . && echo no`

if [ "x$DECISION" == "x" ] ; then
    DECISION=yes
fi
echo '{'
echo '  "autofs": {'
echo "     \"do_automatic_restart\": \"$DECISION\""
echo '  }'
echo '}'
```

So, the output of the script

```
# modules/autofs/facts.d/autofs.sh 
{
  "autofs": {
     "do_automatic_restart": "yes"
  }
}
```

Now we can use the custom fact

```
if $facts['autofs']['do_automatic_restart'] == "no" {                                                                                                                                            
    $_attr = { 'restart' => "logger puppet agent: automounter is NOT going to be RESTARTED due to active containers on a host" }                                                                                                                                                      
} else {                                                                                                                                                                                         
    $_attr = {}                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```